# Angular Style DOM element issue

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to query the DOM and add a style to it in Angular. One would think its simple but the following does not work and gives an error, is there an Angular specific way to do it?

```
let target = document.querySelector(".dom-element");
target.style.width = "100%";
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using ngStyle: https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

```js
[ngStyle]="{width: variableFromController}"
```

Or using `@ViewChild` and `ngAfterViewInit`: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

template:

```
<div #domElement></div>
```

component:

```js
@ViewChild('domElement') element: ElementRef;

public ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.domElement.nativeElement.style.width = '100%';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I understand @ViewChild relies on adding #domElement on the div. Does ViewChild work to query a div id or class also?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the renderer2, you should avoid any direct DOM manipulation. This should do it:

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {

@ViewChild("dom-element") target: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // target is set here
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.target.nativeElement, 'width', '100%');
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I understand @ViewChild relies on adding #domElement on the div. Does ViewChild work to query a div id or class also?

Comment: `@ViewChild` relies only on `#variableName`. You shouldn't access DOM out of angular scope (for example by `document.querySelector` or `docuent.getElementById`). If you need style or class manipulation depending on variable you can also use `ngClass` or `ngStyle`.